# How to ignore SSL certificate validation in node requests?

Tags: node.js, axios, node-fetch

I need to disable peer SSL validation for some of my `https` requests using node.js
Right now I use `node-fetch` package which doesn't have that option, as far as I know.

That should be something like CURL's `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false`

Does any networking package allow to do so? Is there a way to skip SSL validation in axios maybe?

Answer (score 86):

Axios doesn't address that situation so far - you can try:

```
process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = '0';
```

**BUT THAT'S A VERY BAD IDEA** since it disables SSL across the whole node server.

Or, you can configure axios to use a custom agent and set `rejectUnauthorized` to `false` for that agent as mentioned [here](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/535).

Example:

```
const https = require('https');
const axios = require('axios')
//or
// import https from 'https';
// import axios from 'axios';

// At instance level
const instance = axios.create({
  httpsAgent: new https.Agent({  
    rejectUnauthorized: false
  })
});

instance.get('https://something.com/foo');

// At request level
const agent = new https.Agent({  
  rejectUnauthorized: false
});

axios.get('https://something.com/foo', { httpsAgent: agent });
```

Comment: Hmm so I updated my code to include the instance example. I also added `import * as https from 'https';` However, it can't find https

Comment: If using standard node express use 

const https = require('https');

Comment: Jumping in here really late, but i tried adding the httpsAgent on a request level, but it did not seem to work at all.

Comment: @AKJ You might want to open a new question with a minimum, verifiable example, maybe we are able to help.. ;)

Comment: process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = '0'; is must