# Disable SSL in Axios

Tags: javascript, axios

is there an easy way to disable SSL validation in Axios. I tried this `process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = '0';` but it doesn't work.

Here's an example of my code"

```
const postPosts = () => {
  axios
    .post("https://xxx.dev.lab", {
      Username: "xxx",
      Password: "xxx"
    })
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error(error);
    });
};
postPosts();
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54903835/815600

Answer (score 4):

Axios doesn't address that situation so far - you can try:

```
process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = '0';
```

BUT THATS A VERY BAD IDEA since it disables SSL across the whole node server..

or you can configure axios to use a custom agent and set rejectUnauthorized to false for that agent as mentioned here

example:

```
// At instance level
const instance = axios.create({
  httpsAgent: new https.Agent({  
    rejectUnauthorized: false
  })
});

instance.get('https://something.com/foo');

// At request level
 const agent = new https.Agent({  
 rejectUnauthorized: false
});

axios.get('https://something.com/foo', { httpsAgent: agent });
```

Comment: So I updated my code to include the instance level example. Which needs https? I added the import `import https = require('https');` but my TypeScript won't find it

Comment: import * as https from 'https'; you should import this

Comment: where I need to use this code? do I need to write my midleware-node-server to got this working?

Answer (score 0):

**[ IF YOU ARE RUNNING YOUR APP IN DOCKER ]**

I solved that issue in my project with 2 steps:

**1. Change Docker SSL settings**

I edited `/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf` inside the container

Replace strings:

```
TLSv1.2 => TLSv1
SECLEVEL=2 => SECLEVEL=1
```

**2. Set min TLS version for your request**

```js
import * as https from 'https';

const agent = new https.Agent({
  rejectUnauthorized: false,
  minVersion: 'TLSv1',
});

axios.post(
  "https://xxx.dev.lab", 
  { Username: "xxx", Password: "xxx" },
  { httpsAgent: agent }
)
```