# Accessing Kubernetes Cluster through ingress-nginx as proxy from react app running on localhost

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, kubernetes, ssl-certificate, kubernetes-ingress

Apologies if this question is asked before, am new to Kubernetes

Am trying to access the k8s cluster through ingress-nginx as proxy running on my machine, through react app running on localhost

[image]

[image]

Am getting **NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID** Error in my browser.

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54903199/how-to-ignore-ssl-certificate-validation-in-node-requests/54903835) but didn't worked.

How can I get around this?

Thank You.

Comment: Did you create a real TLS certificate for it? Either manually or through cert-manager or through some other vendor tool?

Comment: Hello @coderanger No am not creating a certificate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't install a real TLS certificate, you're just getting the default, self-signed one that the ingress controller includes as a fallback. Check out cert-manager for a path forward or just ignore the error for now (but probably don't ignore it, that's bad).