# How to disable SSL certificate on React Native Axios

Tags: react-native, ssl-certificate

When I call https api on react native axios, it returns `[AxiosError: Network Error]`.
Is there any way to disalble SSL certificate verification in react native?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54903199/how-to-ignore-ssl-certificate-validation-in-node-requests ?

Comment: nope.. https.Agent won't work with the react native as https is the core node module..